# CSS close div float right, link error

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a css button that close a div when click.
the problem is, when I put mouse over this X, it is not working properly.

I put mouse over the X, and the link is not able to click.

the error just happen if I put float:right, but I need this element to be on the right. what can i do? what is the problem?

css:

```
.delete_post{
float:right;
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
border-radius: 30px;
background: #605F61;
font-size: 31px;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 0px;
padding: 11px 3px;
}
```

html:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="delete_post" id="$id">x</a>
```

Comment: where is the code that tells to close a div when you click the X?!!

Comment: please provide a working code sample using the snippet feature or at the very least using jsFiddle that re-creates the problem. Thanks

Comment: Confirmed:  http://jsfiddle.net/5s6aa1d6/  Remove `float: right`, and the x is clickable.

Comment: Ha, just realized, this is an issue with jsFiddle.  The "Result" text in the output frame t has a high z-index.

Comment: Sorry, @renatacosta, I can't duplicate it outside jsFiddle.  If you add `body {margin: 30px;}` to your fiddle, you won't see the problem.

Comment: sorry friends, it was another div with was over .delete_post, like happened with jsFiffle